# PHP / Wordpress - Loading a remote XML file

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, simplepie

How can a get a object variable from a remote XML file, for example [this one](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/artist/Faithless/events.xml) ?

In PHP5 it works fine with **simplexml_load_file()**, but I need this to work in PHP 4 also. How can I do that?
Or is there any built-in WordPress function that can load xml files? I tried using the [WP's SimplePie class](http://wphit.com/lookup/files/wp-includesclass-simplepie-php/), but I get a weird object variable (with incorectly named fields etc).

Comment: The first google result for "parse xml php4" is http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/parsing-xml-using-php4-050816-1046/. Please google before you flood SO with questions that won't help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the smipleXML functions in PHP4  include this class ( I have used it and it works like a charm) 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4484-PHP-Load-XML-files-in-PHP-4-like-SimpleXML-extension.html